Texture gets messed up when exporting animation from Blender to Sketchfab and FAB
I'm facing a problem when exporting an animation from Blender to Sketchfab. The animation and the 3D mesh are sent correctly; however, when I apply the textures, they appear messed up on Sketchfab. Interestingly, when I view the model in the Windows 3D viewer, the textures show up correctly. Additionally, when I export the model without animation, the textures also work fine on Sketchfab.
I have already checked the UV mapping and tried different export formats like FBX and GLTF, but the problem persists only when exporting the model with animation.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I can resolve this texture issue when exporting animations?
Viwer 3D windows:

sketchfab problem textures:



I’ve already figured out what the problem was. It happens when a vertex or edge is too close to another one; for some reason, Sketchfab glitches and causes many issues. It basically merges vertices when they are too close to each other.
